# Connecting keyboard, soundmodule, and a PC

Tags: audio-recording, midi, pc, controller

How do I connect a keyboard, sound module, and pc so that a song played on the keyboard can be played back afterward, but the sounds heard both during the recording and the playback is that of the sound module. Is it the connection shown in the image:

A: http://www.arpegemusic.com/images/midi6.jpg

OR

B: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/4/0/8/computer-topo.png

Comment: What did you observe when you tried each of those topographies?

Comment: I don't have all of the equipment to try it out. but was wondering which was the correct way to for when I do. I am leaning more towards A.

Comment: This seems like a very basic "how do I record audio" sort of question, and a hypothetical one at that. Is that a fair assessment?

Answer (score 0):

Either of those could work, depending on exactly what you are doing. There are also other setups that will work. However, what is not clear from your question is what you consider to be the sound module.

My setup is to have keyboard and other instruments feeding in to my DAW on PC, with various effects loops and a midi sound module connected so I can hook them in, and so I trigger a particular sound bank from my keyboard via the PC.

Answer (score 0):

If I was answering your literal question, it would be setup A but your keyboard has to have the ability to turn local off or you could just lower the volume of the keyboard so it does not output sound. You also said you are a relative beginner...just keep in mind that neither diagram shows how to hook up the audio part of your setup.